# How to access the data in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I made a scaffold and I transferred the code inside the index.html.erb in another file show_league.html.erb, so that my index.html.erb will be my home page and show_league.html.erb will show all the leagues created. Now when I access show_league.html.erb, it gave me this error:

NoMethodError in Leagues#show_league
undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass

This is my show_league.html.erb (which is just the code contained in index.html.erb in the first place):

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>League name</th>
        <th>Commissioner</th>
        <th>League manager</th>
        <th>Venue of games</th>
        <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
    <% @leagues.each do |league| %>
        <tr>
            <td><%= league.league_name %></td>
            <td><%= league.commissioner %></td>
            <td><%= league.league_manager %></td>
            <td><%= league.venue_of_games %></td>
            <td><%= link_to 'Show', league %></td>
            <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_league_path(league) %></td>
            <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', league, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
        </tr>
    <% end %>
</tbody>
```

Please help me.

Comment: Show your Leagues controller. It needs to have smth like `@leagues = League.all`

Comment: Thanks. :) it work. In this case, can I make my def index blank and transfer @leagues = League.all to def show_league?

Comment: Yes, if you are not using `index` route you don't need a controller. Although I think you are little confused about structuring the app. The way I see it you should have a file `leagues_controller.rb` with action `index` and put your `@leagues = League.all` there. Unless you are doing smth unconventional.

Answer (score 2):

The general Rails convention is to have all data given on the `index` and `show` to provide data for a specific instance of the associated index.

```
def index
    @leagues = League.all
end

def show
    @league = League.find(params[:id])
end
```

You can break this convention if you need to but you should have a reason for doing so. Any method can be blank if you don't need it, if you want all data of League it should be `index`, if you want a specific League it should be `show`.

Answer (score 0):

In your `LeaguesController` you need

```
def show_league
  @leagues = League.all
end
```

Comment: yeah. thanks. so is it okay to make my def index blank?

Comment: Does your `index.html.erb` use any instance variables? (variables that start with `@`) If so, they need to be set in the index action.  If the index is now just a static page, you can make the index action empty or even remove it completley.

Comment: But there's a rails saying "convention over configuration" which basically means do things in an expected way.  If I were designing an application like yours I would leave the LeagueController#index method and view showing the `@leagues` values, and maybe make a separate, different page for the home page... HomeController#index